# When I try to mount a location in my container I get a error: Invalid Flag for flag -v: bad mode specified

Tags: docker, tensorflow

I am new to Docker and TensorFlow.

I am trying to get TensorFlow working with Windows using Docker. I am using the command:

```
docker run -dit -v /c/Users/Aditya/notebook:/media/disk -p 8888:8888  
  b.gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow:latest
```

but I am getting the error:

```
invalid value **"C:\\Users\\Aditya\\notebook;
  C:\\Program Files\\Git\\media\\disk" for flag -v: 
  bad mode specified: \Program Files\Git\media\disk
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you check if connecting via ssh to your docker-machine and executing from there the `docker run` command the volumes are created? You can follow the below steps:

```
$ docker-machine ssh default

$ docker run -dit -v /c/Users/Aditya/notebook:/media/disk -p 8888:8888 b.gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow:latest
```

If the issue persists, could you check if updating your Docker to the latest one the issue fixes?